# Prediction with AutoReg command

Tags: python, statsmodels

here is my code  for implementing autoregressive model in python :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yfs
import seaborn as sns
from statsmodels.tsa.api import  acf,graphics,pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg,ar_select_order
data =yfs.download(tickers="AAPL",progress=False,start='2021-01-01',end='2023-01-01')
data.drop(["High","Volume","Low","Close","Adj Close"],axis=1,inplace=True)
data =data.asfreq('d')
data.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(data.head())
# data['percentage_change'] =data['Open'].pct_change()
# print(data.head())
# # data.plot()
# # plt.show()
# data['Open_Difference'] =data['Open'].diff()
# print(data.head())
# data.plot()
# plt.show()
model=AutoReg(data['Open'].ravel(),lags=3,old_names=False)
model =model.fit()
data['prediction'] =model.predict(start=len(data),end=len(data)+10)
# print(model.summary())
# data.plot()
# plt.show()
print(data.head())
```

i am downloading Apple data from yahoo  and  want to implement Autoregressive model (third order)  and also make a prediction, here is  table :

```
       Date        Open
0 2021-01-04  133.520004
1 2021-01-05  128.889999
2 2021-01-06  127.720001
3 2021-01-07  128.360001
4 2021-01-08  132.429993
```

but code shows me error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\Autoregressive_model.py", line 23, in <module>
    data['prediction'] =model.predict(start=len(data),end=len(data)+10)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3980, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4174, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(value)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4915, in _sanitize_column
    com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Data_Science\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 571, in require_length_match
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (11) does not match length of index (503)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

how can i fix it so that i can show graphically original and predicted time series? thanks in advance